# how to find the last value of consecutive values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
df:
col1     col2
 1        10
 1        20
 2        11
 3        33
 1        20
 1        10
 2        24
 3        21
 3        28
```

I want to group by this data frame on col1 where there is consecutive values, and take the last value for each consecutive groups,

The final data frame should look like:

```
df
col1    col2
 1       20
 2       11
 3       33
 1       10
 2       24
 3       28
```

I have tried something like:

```
 df['b_new'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('last')
```

But its missing the consecutive condition.

How to implement it in most effective way using pandas/ python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filtering by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed Series with `-1` for last dupe consecutive rows:

```
df1 = df[df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift(-1))]
print (df1)
   col1  col2
1     1    20
2     2    11
3     3    33
5     1    10
6     2    24
8     3    28
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift(-1)))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
8     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```